# Angular morris donut chart not working

Tags: angularjs, morris.js, donut-chart

I am new to AngularJS and have a requirement to use Donut Chart in my project integrated angular morris donut chart for this. In that, if I pass values as a natural numbers it is working. but if pass "0.00" getting the following error in console. please help to solve this issue.

> raphael-min.js:10 Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M,0,0".
>   raphael-min.js:10 Error:  attribute d: Expected moveto path command ('M' or 'm'), "Z".

Comment: Can you show the Morris code and the data you send to the chart?

Comment: <div donut-chart donut-data='[{label: "Download Sales", value: "0.00"},{label: "In-Store Sales",value: "0.00"},
                                                              {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: "0.00"}]'
                                     donut-colors='["#31C0BE","#c7254e","#98a0d3"]' donut-formatter='"currency"'>
                                </div>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with ','. This is a hypothesis,  but the information is not enough.

Another way is use a cast on javascript '  parseFloat() '

Check your data array on console for view the structure.

Comment: this is my code :                                 <div donut-chart donut-data='[{label: "Download Sales", value: "0.00"},{label: "In-Store Sales",value: "0.00"},
                                                              {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: "0.00"}]'
                                     donut-colors='["#31C0BE","#c7254e","#98a0d3"]' donut-formatter='"currency"'>
                                </div>

Comment: You should try implement with javascript code and a div  http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?html,js,output

Comment: Actually i tried that too, but getting same error. if i pass 0.001 woking fine. this chart not accept zero as a value.

Comment: don't use "0" just 0

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you are using these versions:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-morris/1.3.0/angular-morris.min.js"></script>
```

Your div element does not give me any errors for above versions, and just gives 0 as expected.

```
        <div donut-chart
             donut-data='[{label: "Download Sales", value: "0.00"},
             {label: "In-Store Sales",value: "0.00"},
             {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: "0.00"}]'
             donut-colors='["#31C0BE","#c7254e","#98a0d3"]'
             donut-formatter='"currency"'>
        </div>
```

When I give non zero values, it shows the graph too.

```
        <div donut-chart
             donut-data='[{label: "Download Sales", value: "1.00"},
             {label: "In-Store Sales",value: "2.00"},
             {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: "0.00"}]'
             donut-colors='["#31C0BE","#c7254e","#98a0d3"]'
             donut-formatter='"currency"'>
        </div>
```

I think the version they had when you posted had this bug. The latest version seems to have solved this.